# footer.html is not included when extending the base.html file

Tags: python, django, django-templates, jinja2

In header.html, I have

```
<h1>Header Section</h1>
```

In footer.html, I have

```
<h1>Footer Section</h1>
```

In base.html I have

```
{% include 'header.html'%}
{% block content %} 
{% endblock %}
{% include
'footer.html' %}
```

But when I extend the base template, I only get the header and the content of the page which extends the base. The footer section appears as ***{% include 'footer.html' %}***

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use multiple lines. The Django template engine can not parse this (properly). Put the entire [**`{% include … %}`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include) template tag on a single line:

```
{% include 'header.html'%}
{% block content %} 
{% endblock %}
{% include 'footer.html' %}
```

Comment: Thank you willem. The error is generated dye to autoformat by prettier plugin in VS code. Deactivated the plugin and restarted VS code - fixed the issue

Comment: @jeff: well it might be possible that VS code uses a HTML autoformatter that thus does not "understand" Django template language, and thus formats it the wrong way. But as far as I know, Django's template parser can (currently) not handle template tags that span over multiple lines, so you should prevent that from happening.